# Trying to Resize Eaglview Displayed Image Dependent on Landscape or Portrait Photo

Tags: iphone, opengl-es

I've been trying to figure out how to resize the drawing view on eaglview as opposed to the default 320x480 dimension. My Eaglview is attached to a UIViewController. What I really want to do is find out where viewrenderbuffer is calling its width and height parameters from.

In the code below I can see that the backing width and height are being taken from the binded viewRenderbuffer and through the renderbufferstorage call. I don't want to use the screen default 320x480 though because if I display a landscape photo on portrait view it will be stretched out and vice versa.

```
- (void)reshapeFramebuffer
{
    glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, viewRenderbuffer);
    [context renderbufferStorage:GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES fromDrawable:(CAEAGLLayer*)self.layer];
    glGetRenderbufferParameterivOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_WIDTH_OES, &backingWidth);
    glGetRenderbufferParameterivOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_HEIGHT_OES, &backingHeight);

// This application only needs color. If depth and/or stencil are needed, ensure they are also resized here.
//Debug.h
rt_assert(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE_OES == glCheckFramebufferStatusOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES));
glCheckError();
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Calling `renderbufferStorage:fromDrawable` on the context allocates storage on the Core Animation layer.  The two subsequent calls

```
glGetRenderbufferParameterivOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_WIDTH_OES, &backingWidth);
glGetRenderbufferParameterivOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_HEIGHT_OES, &backingHeight);
```

then obtains the height and width of the renderbuffer which was set when calling `renderbufferStorage:fromDrawable` on the context.

If you want to use a different size for the UIView container, you should set that.  Presumably your EAGLView instance has some provision for resizing subviews, e.g. `- (void)layoutSubviews`...